# VS Code не принимает правильный код реакта и ломает его, а когда запускаю сервер то все работает

Tags: javascript, reactjs

На фото правильный, работающий код ! Но VS Code его ломает. Бывало что в других компонентах пишу код как бы правильно всё, но VS Code его ломает.
Даже в гите нахожу готовый код и вставляю, но всё равно ломает

[image]

Comment: справа внизу есть выбор типа файла, поставьте `react javascript` или исходнику присвойте расширение `.jsx`

Comment: нет, не помогает(((